# LWUIT ComboBox popup theming problem

Tags: java, java-me, combobox, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

I want to customize the look of the ComboBox pop-up list in LWUIT. Nonetheless when I tried to change the `ComboBox`, `ComboBoxFocus`, `ComboBoxItem`, `ComboBoxList`, `ComboBoxPopup` components in LWUIT Theme Creator, nothing happened. The popup preview in Theme Creator still shows the pop-up in black text on white background. 
Am I missing something?
How to change the theme of this pop-up? I am using LWUIT 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following styles in LWUIT resource edit,

- `Unselected#ComboBoxItem#Color` for unfocused list Item.
- `Unselected#ComboBoxPopup#Color` for unfocused list Item.
- `Selected#ComboBoxItem#Color` for focused list Item.

**Note:** uncheck derive checkbox and change the fore color or background color. Because its use default style When the derive checkbox is selected.

Comment: That works. I didn't realize that they were split into separate components. Thanks :)

One note though. Custom list cell renderer won't show custom themes unless we change the values you mentioned above.