# lwuit calendar with button event

Tags: java-me, calendar, popup, lwuit

i tried to show the calendar on button click using form but i'm unable to *change the date* and very much struggled to find where the *focus* .

```
    ...
    Button mdate=new Button("change date");
    mdate.addActionListener(this);
    ...
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
       Form cal= new Form();
       com.sun.lwuit.Calendar c =new com.sun.lwuit.Calendar();
       c.setFocus(true);
       c.addActionListener(this);
       cal.addComponent(c);
       cal.show();
    }
```

how to show and hide calendar on button click in a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better you can use `Dialog` (like pop up) instead of Form. You can easily dispose within a `Form`. No need to show another form. See the below sample code,

```
Button button = new Button("Click me");
form.addComponent(button);
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        final Dialog cal = new Dialog();
        final com.sun.lwuit.Calendar c = new com.sun.lwuit.Calendar();
        c.setFocus(true);
        c.addActionListener(this);
        cal.addComponent(c);
        cal.addCommand(new Command("Cancel") {

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
              cal.dispose();
            }
        });
      c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("Selected date :: " + c.getDate().toString())
        }
     });
    cal.show(20, 20, 20, 20, true, false);
    }
});
```

And add the selected and unselected style for `Calendar` like `CalendarSelectedDay`, `CalendarDate`. Also add the [selected and unselected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893089/lwuit-combobox-popup-theming-problem/6894833#6894833) style for `ComboBox`.

Comment: how can i can add event to calendar to particular date selected..
Please help